# Pandas: Loop through dataframe with out counter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` which has dates in it:

```
df['Survey_Date'].head(4)
Out[65]: 
0    1990-09-28
1    1991-07-26
2    1991-11-23
3    1992-10-15
```

I am interested in calculating a metric between two of the dates, using a separate data frame `flow_df`.

`flow_df` looks like:

```
        date   flow
0 1989-01-01   7480
1 1989-01-02   5070
2 1989-01-03   6410
3 1989-01-04  10900
4 1989-01-05  11700
```

For instance, I would like to query another data frame based on the `current_date` and `early_date`.  The first time period of interest would be:

```
current_date = 1991-07-26
early_date = 1990-09-28
```

I have written a clunky for loop and it gets the job done, but I am sure there is a more elegant way:

My approach with a counter and for loop:

```
def find_peak(early_date,current_date,flow_df):
    mask = (flow_df['date']>= early_date) & (flow_df['date'] < current_date)
    query = flow_df.loc[mask]
    peak_flow = np.max(query['flow'])*0.3048**3
    return peak_flow

n=0
for thing in df['Survey_Date'][1:]:
    early_date = df['Survey_Date'][n]
    current_date = thing
    peak_flow = find_peak(early_date,current_date,flow_df)
    n+=1
    df['Avg_Stage'][n] = peak_flow
```

How can I do this without a counter and for loop?

The desired output looks like:

```
  Survey_Date   Avg_Stage
0  1990-09-28  
1  1991-07-26  574.831986
2  1991-11-23  526.693347
3  1992-10-15  458.732915
4  1993-04-01  855.168767
5  1993-11-17  470.059653
6  1994-04-07  419.089330
7  1994-10-21  450.237861
8  1995-04-24  498.376500
9  1995-06-23  506.871554
```

Comment: You mean you want to select the period between `early-date` and `current-date`?

Comment: yes,  but my question is how to loop through the data frame with the dates of interest.

Comment: In your dataframe there is nothing between `early-date` and `current-date`. Can you post a desired output?

Comment: Please define _Do stuff_. If you're looking to grab the time difference between two dates, then convert column to `pandas datetime`, apply a `shift` and subtract. `df.Survey_Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Survey_Date); df['difference'] = (df.Survey_Date - df.Survey_Date.shift()).fillna(0)`.

Comment: @Abdou I edited the question.

Comment: @OhadEytan It is correct how it is written.  It assigns the `peak _flow` value to `current_date` record's `Avg_Stage` column.  That is why I did not include so much detail in my first go around.

Comment: I still think you should post the output you want. That will make it easier for you to get the right answer.

Comment: @JoeR  It works as it is written, I am just looking for a more efficient way to code it.  I have used `df.apply(lambda row: )` to do row-wise calculations, but don't know how to approach the problem when I need to access items from two rows. I will think about how to re-word it, but I dont know all of the lingo.  Yet...

Comment: if it works, why not show head for final output, so We can see if there is a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new variable that identifies survey period and use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` to avoid `for` loop. It should be much faster when `flow_df` is large.

```
#convert both to datetime, if they are not
df['Survey_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Survey_Date'])
flow_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(flow_df['date'])

#Merge Survey_Date to flow_df. Most rows of flow_df['Survey_Date'] should be NaT
flow_df = flow_df.merge(df, left_on='date', right_on='Survey_Date', how='outer')

# In case not all Survey_Date in flow_df['date'] or data not sorted by date.
flow_df['date'].fillna(flow_df['Survey_Date'], inplace=True)
flow_df.sort_values('date', inplace=True)

#Identify survey period. In your example: [1990-09-28, 1991-07-26) is represented by 0; [1991-07-26, 1991-11-23) = 1; etc.
flow_df['survey_period'] = flow_df['Survey_Date'].notnull().cumsum()

#calc Avg_Stage in each survey_period. I did .shift(1) because you want to align period [1990-09-28, 1991-07-26) to 1991-07-26 
df['Avg_Stage'] = (flow_df.groupby('survey_period')['flow'].max()*0.3048**3).shift(1)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  `flow_df`is quite large and for statements are clunky.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for early_date, current_date in zip(df['Survey_Date'], df['Survey_Date'][1:]):
    #do whatever yo want.
```

Of course you can put it into a list comprehension:

```
[some_metric(early_date, current_date) for early_date, current_date in zip(df['Survey_Date'], df['Survey_Date'][1:])]
```

Comment: Nice, that is getting closer to what I am after.

Comment: If you wish more you need to be more precise in your question

Comment: I thought simply saying I don't want to use a for loop would be enough detail, but I went back and edited my original post to include more details.